# Why am I getting the message "Single-stepping until exit . . . which has no line number information" in GDB?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I've compiled my C program using **gcc 4.4.1** using the flag `-g`, but when I try to step through one of my functions in **gdb version 7.0**, I get the message:

```
"Single stepping until exit from function _DictionaryTree_getNodeList, 
which has no line number information."
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just guessing, but is _DictionaryTree_getNodeList in another file that wasn't compiled with -g?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out before I even read your answer.  Good guess ;)

Comment: If you are compiling multiple files, it's better to use a Makefile and add -ggdb in the gcc option flags.

Comment: @Manav MN yeah, that's what I have, but I have two different commands - one for compiling and one for linking and I forgot to add the flag to the one for compiling (which is actually the only one I needed it for, I guess).

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem but in my case adding `-g` to the compiler wasn't enough so I used `-ggdb` as suggested by Manav.

Comment: I commented out almost all the code from my main. After the last line in main, gdb went to the first line of main, then got this strange message. I tried with this CXXFLAG="-ggdb -O0", still got the same error message. Tried gdb gcc 7.3 and 8.2 both got the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

**In my case, the problem was version skew between `gcc` and `gdb`**.

After landing here from search and none of these answers fit my situation, I figured out that (because of aliases / symlinks / `Makefile` / environment variables) I was accidentally using a newer GCC (4.8.x) and an older GDB (7.2). **Stepping up to a newer version of GDB (7.8) fixed the problem.** For some reason, using a newer GCC and older GDB didn't work.

Comment: ... but (only) now I see that previous answers to other nearly-identical questions have this answer -- e.g., [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20493816/3562032) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18408197/3562032). The latter includes information on *why* (DWARF incompatibility). Upvotes all around!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message too but the source of my problem was different. If anyone is still having any problems, make sure you have `#include <stdio.h>` in your file, with the the appropriate brackets around `stdio.h` (the text message would not show up if I had it around `stdio.h`).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I was debugging a shared library without pointing LD_LIBRARY_PATH to correct location with debug endstates.

you can use

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<location of the debug build of the .so file>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Hopefully this is helpful to someone

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, when I compiled a file using -g option and without -g option.
For one of the file, the gdb showed line number without any issues(even when it was compiled without -g option)..
And for the other file, I had to explicitly mention -g flag...

**Any ideas as to whether the source file could be loaded at run time in
 GDB with cross referencing would be good solution... by mapping the
 lines to the addresses :D.**

Answer (score -1):

I had the same trouble despite I was already compiling with `-g2`. Changing it to `-g3` did the trick.