# GDB: How to print the current line or find the current line number?

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb

The `list` command prints a set of lines, but I need one single line: where I currently am and where an error has probably occurred.

Comment: `backtrace` or `where`, even `info line` or just simply `bt` (for backtrace).  http://www.dirac.org/linux/gdb/ for a gdb tutorial

Comment: `bt` or `backtrace` or `where` print stack of function calls, `f` or `frame` print next line to execute.

Comment: for others answers, see the same question here : [GDB: How to check current line number during debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657288/gdb-how-to-check-current-line-number-during-debug)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I do get the same information while debugging. Though not while I am checking the stacktrace. Most probably you would have used the optimization flag I think. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170246/why-am-i-getting-the-message-single-stepping-until-exit-which-has-no-line) - something related.

Try compiling with `-g3` remove any optimization flag. 
Then it might work. 
HTH!

Comment: Ah, so although my program was compiled with `-g` to contain debug info, I'm currently in a stack frame, taken from one of shared libraries, which apparently wasn't compiled to contain line information. Thanks, kumar.

Comment: Comment of the year award. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 149):

The 'frame' command will give you what you are looking for. (This can be abbreviated just 'f'). Here is an example:

```
(gdb) frame
\#0  zmq::xsub_t::xrecv (this=0x617180, msg_=0x7ffff00008e0) at xsub.cpp:139
139         int rc = fq.recv (msg_);
(gdb)
```

Without an argument, 'frame' just tells you where you are at (with an argument it changes the frame). More information on the frame command can be found [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Frames.html).

Answer (score 47):

Command **where** or **frame** can be used. where command will give more info with the function name

Answer (score 23):

Keep in mind that gdb is a powerful command -capable of low level instructions- so is tied to assembly concepts.

What you are looking for is called de instruction pointer, i.e:

> The instruction pointer register points to the memory address which the processor will next attempt to execute. The instruction pointer is called **ip** in 16-bit mode, **eip** in 32-bit mode,and **rip** in 64-bit mode.

more detail [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language)

all registers available on gdb execution can be shown with:

```
(gdb) info registers
```

with it you can find which mode your program is running (looking which of these registers exist)

then (here using most common register **rip** nowadays, replace with **eip** or very rarely **ip** if needed):

```
(gdb)info line *$rip
```

will show you line number and file source

```
(gdb) list *$rip
```

will show you that line with a few before and after

but probably

```
(gdb) frame
```

should be enough in many cases.

Comment: GDB doesn't support 16-bit mode I believe, so `ip` is never used here. Also, instead of explicitly spelling the name of program counter, you can use GDB's alias for it: `$pc`. So `x/10i $pc` will disassemble 10 instructions at current instruction pointer regardless of architecture — it will work on i386, x86_64, ARM etc..

Answer (score 15):

All the other answers are correct, but what I prefer is to use [TUI mode](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or `tui enable`) which shows your location and the function in a separate window which is very helpful for the users.

Hope that helps too.