# GDB: How to check current line number during debug

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

How do I check the current line number that I'm stopped in when debugging with GDB?  I would have thought this would be obvious (and maybe it is) but I don't see it on the [GDB Cheat Sheet](http://darkdust.net/files/GDB%20Cheat%20Sheet.pdf).

Comment: possible duplicate of [gdb: how to print the current line or find the current line number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581837/gdb-how-to-print-the-current-line-or-find-the-current-line-number)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Some digging around revealed the following methods:

1. `frame`:  This command was exactly what I was looking for.  Output looked as follows:

   ```
   (gdb) frame
   #0  MyDialog::on_saveButton_clicked (this=0x72bf9e0) at src/ui/dialog/MyDialog.cxx:86
   86          _item->save();
   (gdb)
   ```
2. `where` or `bt` (same effect):  This prints out the call stack, ending on the current line.
3. `list *$pc`:  This doesn't tell you the exact line but it prints out the surrounding lines with the current line in the center.

Comment: I know you mention GDB but just as a suggestion have you tried using gdbtui? It has a nice terminal GUI that let's you see the current and surround lines. You can also scroll up down using the keyboard directional keys.

Comment: @Nobilis Thanks for the tip!  gdbtui looks pretty sweet!

Answer (score 0):

`x/i $eip`
eip(rip) points to the next instruction