# line number information lost during linking in gcc

Tags: debugging, gcc, linker, gdb

I'm using Red Hat 4.4.7-3 and gcc 4.8.3

I have code in two files(test.c and sum.c) and I compiled them separately with gcc(with debug information). In the last phase when I'm making the final output by combining both files, debug information is lost.

```
test.c:

int main()
{

    int a=5,b=7;
    int c=testsum(a,b);

    printf("%d + %d=%d\n",a,b,c);
    return 0;
}



sum.c:
int testsum(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

I did the following:

```
gcc -c -g test.c -o test.o
gcc -c -g sum.c -o sum.o

gcc -g test.o sum.o -o output
```

When I do gdb sum.o then it is showing the line number information

```
(gdb) l testsum
1   int testsum(int a, int b)
2   {
3       return a+b;
4   }
```

but with the gdb output I'm not getting line number information.

```
(gdb) l testsum 
No line number known for testsum.
(gdb)
```

I repeated the same thing on my personal laptop(gcc-4.8.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1) and here it is working perfectly fine. But I need the debug information in the final output on the redhat machine for some project.

Any suggestions/comments regarding obtaining the line number information in final executable would be much appreciated.

Comment: BTW: just tried this on uptodate CentOS 6.5 32&64 bit (gcc 4.4.7-4, binutils 2.20.51... and gdb 7.2) and it this works as expected. It also works fine with developers toolset (2.1). It seem you have something messed up on your system.

Comment: This answer may apply: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18408197/2554472 . gcc 4.8 will by default emit debugging info in a format that can't be recognized by older versions of gdb.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile and link with `gcc -g`. Perhaps you forgot the `-g` flag at link time.

And use surely want to compile with `gcc -Wall -g` since warnings are incredibly useful.

You should run `gdb` on the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable file, not on object files (so <strike>`gdb sum.o`</strike> is wrong):

```
gdb ./output
```

You should have a `Makefile` (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108)) and build your program using GNU `make`

Perhaps the `gdb` on the remote Redhat server is not accepting the same [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format than on your local laptop. Check the versions of `gdb`. (Perhaps consider compiling on the remote sever, or passing some explicit [debugging option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) like `-gdwarf-3` or whatever is appropriate for the remote `gdb` to your `gcc` laptop compiler).