# gdb debugger accessing files that are not found

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, terminal, gdb

I am trying to do something rather simple, but don't understand why I am getting an error.  I have a Makefile I will include so you can see what is going on.  But when I step through the program I get `libc-start.c: No such file or directory`.  Is there a way to handle this in the Makefile or avoid this?

Makefile

```
# makefile to build a program

# program depends on components: name and main 
myname:      main.o name.o 
    g++ -g -ggdb  main.o name.o -o myname

# name.cpp has it's own header file
name.o:        name.cpp name.h
    g++ -c -g -ggdb  name.cpp

# main.cpp also uses the header file name.h
main.o:        main.cpp name.h
    g++ -c -g -ggdb main.cpp

clean:
    /bin/rm -f myname *.o
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "name.h"

int main () {
    name myName;

    myName.SetLast(LAST);
    myName.SetMiddle(MI);
    myName.SetFirst(FIRST);

    cout <<"My name is: ";
    myName.PrintFirst();
    myName.PrintMiddle();
    myName.PrintLast();

    return 0;
}
```

name.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "name.h"

void name::GetFirst(string str) {
    str=first;
}

void name::SetFirst(string str) {
    first=str;
}

void name::GetMiddle(string str) {
    str=middle;
}

void name::SetMiddle(string str) {
    middle=str;
}

void name::GetLast(string str) {
    str=last;
}

void name::SetLast(string str) {
    last=str;
}

void name::PrintLast() {
    cout << last << "\n";
}
void name::PrintMiddle() {
    cout << middle;
}
void name::PrintFirst() {
    cout << first;
}
```

name.h

```
#define LAST    "Tank-Engine"
#define MI  "T. "
#define FIRST   "Thomas "

class name {

    private:
    string first;
    string middle;
    string last;

    public:
    void SetFirst(string str);
    void GetFirst(string str);

    void SetMiddle(string str);
    void GetMiddle(string str);

    void SetLast(string str);
    void GetLast(string str);

    void PrintLast();
    void PrintMiddle();
    void PrintFirst();

};
```

gdb error when stepping through

```
name::PrintLast (this=0x7fffffffe4a0) at name.cpp:31
31      cout << last << "\n";
(gdb) s
My name is: Thomas T. Tank-Engine
32  }
(gdb) s
main () at main.cpp:18
18          return 0;
(gdb) s
name::~name (this=0x7fffffffe4a0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at name.h:5
5   class name {
(gdb) s
main () at main.cpp:19
19  }
(gdb) s
__libc_start_main (main=0x400b86 <main()>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe5b8, init=<optimized out>, 
fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe5a8) at libc-start.c:323
323 libc-start.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) s
__GI_exit (status=0) at exit.c:104
104 exit.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) s
103 in exit.c
(gdb) s
104 in exit.c
(gdb) s
__run_exit_handlers (status=0, listp=0x7ffff78ae698 <__exit_funcs>, 
run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true) at exit.c:35
35  in exit.c
(gdb)
```

Comment: Add two flags to `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`: `-g3 -O0`. `-g3` will include symbolic defines, and `-O0` may help with `<optimized out>`. Also see [Compile with -g option but “Single stepping until exit from function main, which has no line number information”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20474668/608639). The cited question says to update GDB. Have you run `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` recently?

Comment: Should I add those flags to the Makefile?  And yes I have updated everything.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> But when I step through the program I get `libc-start.c: No such file or directory`

There is *no actual problem* here (and GDB is most certainly *not* failing).

What's happening is that you step past the *end* of your program, and into `libc` (which is compiled with debug info, but you have not installed sources for it).

Many programmers believe that the execution of their program starts with `main`, and ends when `main` returns. But actually there are 1000s of instructions that run *before and after* `main`, as `libc` prepares your program for execution, and then cleans up after it. Unless you are a libc developer, *usually* you don't care about these before and after steps, and shouldn't try to step through that code.

Comment: You are correct.  The gdb isn't failing.  I apologize for the misleading of the title.  I corrected that mistake.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: In the case of a buffer overflow exploit, how can I find the address of libc if I'm getting that error?