# Unable to open 'libc-start.c'

Tags: c, ubuntu, debugging, gdb, libc

I'm trying to debug my C code in vscode, and I'm having some problems.
I'm using ubuntu and have gcc and gdb debugger installed. when I start debugging my code and reach to a line with `printf` or `scanf`, I get this error:
`Unable to open 'libc-start.c': Unable to read file '/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/csu/libc-start.c' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file '/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/csu/libc-start.c').`
I read some answers to this question saying I have to install `glibc-source`, and I did that. then I added this to my launch.json:

```
"sourceFileMap": {
                "/build/glibc-S7xCS9": "/usr/src/glibc"
          }
```

still nothing's changed.
do you know anything that could help me? I could provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did that. then I added this to my launch.json:
>
> ```
> "sourceFileMap": {
>                "/build/glibc-S7xCS9": "/usr/src/glibc"
>          }
> ```

Your error mentions `/build/glibc-eX1tMB/...`. You should change `glibc-S7xCS9` to `glibc-eX1tMB` in your `.json` file.

(The directory `/build/glibc-....` is a *temporary* directory created for each separate build. You would need to change it every time you update your GLIBC version.)

> I'm having some problems.

Note that there [isn't an actual problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42017254/50617), *unless* you need to debug GLIBC internals.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I find this unique-identifier without the error message? VSCode seems to be able to find the glibc source code so it doesn't show error message, but I'm sure the unique identifier is wrong, and that's the reason it doesn't step into the source code.