# Single stepping until exit from function main, which has no line number information

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I've seen a similar thread here on stackoverflow

[Why am I getting the message "Single-stepping until exit . . . which has no line number information" in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170246/why-am-i-getting-the-message-single-stepping-until-exit-which-has-no-line)

By the moment the accepted answer does not solve my problem.

What I do is to set a breakpoint at the main-function

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x6fe
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/bjorn/printprog 

Breakpoint 1, 0x00005555555546fe in main ()
(gdb)
```

so far so god but when I start stepping I get the following:

```
(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
hell world!!!!
Number of characters in the string are 14
__libc_start_main (main=0x5555555546fa <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdef8, init=<optimized 
out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdee8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:344
344 ../csu/libc-start.c: Filen eller katalogen finns inte.
```

"Filen eller katalogen finns inte." means "the file or catalog does not exist"

What could the problem be?

- Something seems to be missing, is that the cause - start.c, do I need that file?
- that versions differ between gcc and gdb?

GDB

```
 GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
```

GCC

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
```

- or could it be that my makefile is wrong or missing something?

makefile

```
  CC=gcc
  CFLAGS=-I.
  printprog: main.o print.o 
      $(CC) -g -o printprog main.o print.o -I.
```

Comment: Add the `-g` compile option to your `CFLAGS`. It doesn't do much good on your link command line.

Comment: @FredLarson - thanks that solved the problem :)

Comment: Good! I made an answer out of my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appears to be happening is that your files are being compiled using an implicit rule, then the object files are linked using the rule you specify. Since your `-g` option is on the link command, not the compile command, it's too late. The compilation has already been done without debug information.

Rather, add the `-g` option to your `CFLAGS` symbol. This is used in the implicit rule, so the source files will be compiled with debug information. The option is not needed for linking (and `-I.` shouldn't be necessary either for compiling or linking).

```
  CC=gcc
  CFLAGS= -g
  printprog: main.o print.o 
      $(CC) -o printprog main.o print.o
```